# How to map UI element states to an identifier received from the backend

Tags: qt, qml, state

I am fairly new to Qt/QML and I am currently experimenting with it. In my current setup my backend is C++ and the front-end is QML. The backend sends signals to the QML layer which then reacts and changes accordingly.

The basic idea is that the UI will have 4 buttons which are disabled and not visible by default. When a "Add" signal is received from the backend it will enable the first disabled button it finds. Also when the "Add" signal is received the user will be prompted to enter a custom name which will be displayed as the button text. When a "Remove" signal is received with the backend ID that specific button will be disabled and no longer visible.

In the center there is a rectangle which can display 3 colors: (grey = no_status; red = Error; green = OK). The status will be coming from the backend with a backendID. When one of the buttons is pressed it will show the status of the backned ID. But each button will have its on status.

Some how I need to map the backend ID I get from the backend to the UI elements and there states. Can I get some help on figuring out on how to do this?

QML Code:

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
           spacing: 10
           y: 10
           Button {id: btn1; visible: true; enabled: true }
           Button {id: btn2; visible: true; enabled: true }
           Button {id: btn3; visible: true; enabled: true }
           Button {id: btn4; visible: true; enabled: true }
       }

       Connections {
           target: backend
           onAdd: {
               handleAdd(backEndID)
           }
           onRemove: {
                 handleRem(backEndID)
           }

           onStatusUpdate: {
               handleStatusUpdate(backEndID)
           }

       }

       Dialog {
           id: inputBox
           modal: true
           Textfield: { id: input; .....}
           onAccepted: {
               handleUserInput(input.text)
           }
       }

       Rectangle {
           anchors.centerIn: parent
           id: box
           color: "grey"
           width: 200
           height: 200
       }

       QtObject {
           id: controller
           property var btnName: qsTr("")
           property variant btns: [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]
          function handleAdd(name) { btnName = name; inputBox.open(); }
          function handleUserInput(btnText) { enableBtn(btnText) }

          function enableBtn(btnText) {
              for (var i = 0; i < btns.length(); i++) {
                  if (!btns[i].enabled) {
                      btns[i].enabled = true
                      btns[i].visible = true
                      btns[i].text = btnText
                  }
              }
          }
       }

}
```

Mock UI

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you add a property to each button so they know their own backendID?

Answer (score 0):

you can move your connection code into each Button and add a new property to each button as backendID, when add or remove signal was emit each button check backendID with their ID.

or

you can add objectName to each button "Button1", "Button2",... and directly find the button from the C++ side and change their properties like enable or visible.

Comment: Thank you that helps. I decided to move the connection into the button.

Comment: @developer_in_the_making  it's good. so checked the above post as an answer for other visitors.